# Table: categorie from column to row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some tables (Exel, CSV) I have to import in my MySQL database.

These tables look like this:

[image: actual table]

For using this table in my database I need it like this:

[image: I need the table like this]

I've thousands of rows in my tables. It would be very difficult to add everything manually. Is there a way (some special app, PHP code, SQL code, Apple Script) to do this automatically?

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: There will be some code available after you write it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But unfortunately I'm a beginner at coding and I think I'm not able to code this.

Comment: Try one thing at a time. First try choose your favourite programming language, then look how you can make a connection with SQL, then find out how the SQL queries work, then work out how you can loop through the rows in your CSV file, finally put everything together. If you are getting stuck with one of the parts and you need help, come back to SO.com with the code you tried.

Comment: I finally found a very, very simple solution: I used this function in Numbers for Mac: WENN(ISTLEER(B5);A5;C4)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a very, very simple solution:

I used this function in Numbers for Mac: `WENN(ISTLEER(B5);A5;C4)`